# How wait for previous calls end in AngularJS forEach with promises

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, foreach, promise, angular-promise

I've a problem with an `forEach` loop where I call an AngularJS promise every iteration. The web service method call a SQL Server stored procedure that inserts a record in a table the ID that I give to it if doesn't exist.

The stored procedure is something like this...

```
-- Other code before

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE TableId = @Id) = 0
    INSERT...

-- Other code after
```

And javascript code is something like this...

```
this.callSP = function ($scope, id) {

    return $http({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/Project/webservice.svc/Call_SP',
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            "ID": id
        }
    });
};

myArrayOfIds.forEach(function (item) {
    var promise = $WebService.callSP($scope
        , item // id);

    promise.then(function (results) {
        // Do something...            
    }, function (error, status, headers, config) {
        // Do something...
    }).finally(function() {
        // Do something...
    });
});
```

`myArrayOfIds` could contains multiple elements and `TableId` is the primary key of the table so sometime happens that the first two iterations call concurrently the stored procedure and both try to insert the record in the table with the result that one of them fails for primary key violation.

Is there anyway to wait for all previous call end?

Comment: did you want each iteration to wait for the previous iteration to complete before continuing?

Comment: Well, just don't use `forEach`. With `map`, you can get back an array of promises, and await them all with `$q.all`

Comment: I think he wants to perform each iteration in series

Comment: or, only one `$WebService.callSP` at a time

Comment: I've to call the store procedure for each array item, in the real situation the array contains some other variables that I've to pass to each web service call. The array is something like `[ { id: 1, value: 'firstValue' }, { id: 1, value: 'secondValue' } ]`, the `id` is the same but the `value` changes in every item.

Answer (score 0):

I'll break out my old crappy promise queue

```
var PromiseQueue = (function() {
    'use strict';
    var PromiseQueue = function() {
        this.queue = [Promise.resolve(true)];
    };
    PromiseQueue.prototype.add = function(fn) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.shift(); // 
        (function(q, args) {
            q.unshift(function() {
                var done = function() {
                    q.pop();
                    return fn.apply(null, args);
                };
                return q[0].then(done, done);
            }());
        }(this.queue, args));
    };
    return PromiseQueue;
}());
```

This can then be used in your case like

```
var pq = new PromiseQueue();

myArrayOfIds.forEach(function (item) {
    pq.add(function (item) {
        var promise = $WebService.callSP($scope, item); // id);

        promise.then(function (results) {
            // Do something...            
        }, function (error, status, headers, config) {
            // Do something...
        }).finally(function() {
            // Do something...
        });
        return promise;
    }, item);
});
```